# sorting huge file that is almost sorted

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, optimization

I'm facing with the following problem:

- I have a huge file (let's say 30 GB), that is streamed in memory with a specific API.

  - This API only allows me to read going forward (not backward). But the files can be read as many times as I want.
  - The file contains data that is almost all sorted, as in, 99% of the data is sorted but it can happen that a record is not in its correct position and should have been inserted much before if everything was sorted.

I'm trying to create a duplicate of this file, except it would need to be sorted.

Is there a graceful way to do this ?

The only way I can think of is the most generic way:

- read the file
- create batch of a few GB of memory, sort them, write them to a file on the HDD
- use external merge to merge all these temporary files into the final output

However this is not using the specificities that the data is "almost" sorted. Would there be a better way to do this ? For instance without using external files on the HDD?

Comment: Seems trivial - put elements out or order in a 300 MB priority queue, merge. Where's the catch?

Comment: Search for **(external) merge sorting**.  It chops data into manageable chunks, sorts each chunk individually, and then merges all chunks together.

Comment: this is what I'm proposing at the end of my question, however I'd like to know if there is a way that would work better knowing that the structure of my data is specific

Comment: You'll find that with a replacement-selection distribution pass you'll probably only end up with two files to merge, possibly even only one, if the input is nearly sorted already.

Comment: If all the out-of-order elements appear after the place where they should be, you can just walk over the file, split it into the sorted and the unsorted part (unsorted elements are simply those that are smaller than the most recently seen element of the sorted subet), sort the unsorted part (which shouldn't be a problem, given that it is so small), and then merge the two.

Comment: I can't see any point in searching for special cases like that. Just sort-merge it like any other file.

Comment: @Wintermute I think, you've answered the question quite nicely. Would you mind making a real answer out of it?

Comment: I don't. I think it's mad. Does your input really conform to that specification? What if it doesn't? Implement something else? Just sort-merge. Note that the description above of external sorting is only correct of a poor implementation. A proper implementation will use replacement-selection distribution, which forms the chunks *by sorting,* not before sorting, and has two desirable properties: (1) the chunks are on average twice the memory size, and (2) the more sorted the input, the larger and fewer the chunks. A completely sorted input will only produce one chunk.

Comment: @EJP There are valid use cases that really do guarantee that the data is almost sorted. I have seen one once that called for a simple *insertion* sort as a very good optimization, any other algorithm would have been plain and simple overkill. Regarding this question I can imagine that it is about handling log-infos from several sources that needs to be in clock order, but where some records may be delayed a long time due to load. Optimization must take these peculiarities into account because they can yield orders of magnitude improvements.

Comment: @Wintermute: `If all the out-of-order elements appear after the place where they should be` - if you think about the alternatives, that's just a matter of definition (and frequency/probability).

Comment: @greybeard That is technically true, but if single elements appear before the place where they should be, you end up taking potentially quite large sorted blocks as part of the "unsorted" set. It's the "should have been inserted much before if everything was sorted." part of the question leads me to believe that this very simple approach might reliably isolate the smallest unsorted set. If that is not the case, the approach I suggested is unlikely to give good performance.

Comment: @PetrVepřek: a decent external merge forms initial runs using priority queues (essentially one, even in multi-way-merge), achieving an expected run length of twice the capacity of the queue.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this (example in Python)

```
last = None
special = []
for r in records:
    if last is None or r > last:
        last = r
    else:
        special.append(r)
        if len(special) > max_memory:
            break
if len(special) > max_memory:
    # too many out of sequence records, use a regular sort
    ...
else:
    sort(special)
    i = 0
    for r in records:
        while i < len(special) and special[i] < r:
            write(special[i])
            i += 1
        write(r)
    while i < len(special):
        write(special[i])
        i += 1
```

Comment: If there is also a significant number of records that are very near to where they should be, it might be beneficial to add a small circular sorting buffer to the first pass. This buffer could be kept in order with a simple insertion sort and could significantly reduce the number of records that end up in the `special` array.

Answer (score 1):

Use a variation of bottom up merge sort called natural merge sort. The idea here is to find runs of ordered data, then repeatedly merge those runs back and forth between two files (all sequential I/O) until there's only a single run left. If the sort doesn't have to be stable (preserve the order of equal elements), then you can consider a run boundary to occur whenever a pair of sequential elements are out of order. This eliminates some housekeeping. If the sort needs to be stable, then you need to keep track of run boundaries on the initial pass that finds the runs, this could be an array of counts (the size of each run). Hopefully this array would fit in memory. After each merge pass, the number of counts in the array is cut in half, and once there's only a single count, the sort is done.

Wiki article (no sample code given though): [natural bottom up merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Natural_merge_sort) .

If all the out of order elements consist of somewhat isolated records, you could separate the out of order elements into a third file, only copying in order records from the first file to the second file. Then you sort the third file with any method you want (bottom up merge sort is probably still best if the third file is large), then merge the second and third files to create a sorted file.

If you have multiple hard drives, keep the files on separate drives. If doing this on a SSD drive, it won't matter. If using a single hard drive, reading or writing a large number of records at a time, like 10MB to 100MB per read or write, will greatly reduce the seek overhead during the sort process.